# Extracting a word from a string if contained in a list (in R)

Tags: r

I have one vector of strings, for example one element is :

```
"MG08-004121-0040 : LECTOR DE CODIGO DE BARRAS MARCA DATALOGIC MODELO MAGELLAN 800i  ALIMENTACION ELECTRICA 5 Vcc"
```

and I have another vector of strings to match on:

```
c("EC", "DATALOGIC", "SONY")
```

I want to return (if any) the *word* in the first string if it matches to one word of the list.

In the example it should return `DATALOGIC`

Any ideas?

Comment: Careful with the word *list*, a list is a particular class in R.  `c("EC", "DATALOGIC", "SONY")` is a vector, and it's very different from `list("EC", "DATALOGIC", "SONY")`. (I edited your question to remove the word "list".)

Comment: You are right. I was programming in `python` and switch to `R`. I already edited the comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can combine the elements of the second vector to form a regex expression:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, paste0("\\b", paste(y, collapse="|"), "\\b"))
[1] "DATALOGIC"
```

Comment: If I use the vector of strings of the question, it works, but if I use a bigger vector it fails. Do you know why?

Comment: Take off the `[[1]]`

Comment: I just saw the error, In my vector I have: `c("EC", "", "DATALOGIC", "SONY")` if I remove the empty space: `y <- y[y!='']` It is fixed... weird...

Comment: Do you really have a `list` or is it just a vector?

Comment: This is happening: `str_extract_all("MG08-004121-0040 : LECTOR DE CODIGO DE BARRAS MARCA DATALOGIC MODELO MAGELLAN 800i  ALIMENTACION ELECTRICA 5 Vcc", paste0("\\b", paste(marcas, collapse='|'), "\\b"))[[1]] 
 [1] "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"         "EC"        "DATALOGIC" "ELO"       "0"         "0"         "EC"      ` Any ideas?

Comment: I will not go back and forth and hold your hand while you implement the unknown part of your code with the clear solution that I provided. You can remove your acceptance check mark and downvote if you want. I showed you that it works. If you are unwilling to post the variety of your real data I cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
intersect(strsplit(string,'\\s')[[1]],vec)
#[1] "DATALOGIC"
```